# Jquery set background color not working

Tags: jquery, css

guys I'm trying to set the backgroundColor of a draggable element through Jquery ".css()" function. The attribute backgroundColor actually change It's value, but somehow the color Itself don't change.

My code:

```
var $nDiv = $('<div></div>')
$nDiv.draggable(); 
var color = "rgba(120,120,120)";
canvas.append($nDiv);
$nDiv.css('backgroundColor',color);
```

Comment: If the attribute changes, but the color doesn't, something else in your CSS is overriding it. Maybe you have a style with `!important`?

Answer (score 3):

You used the `rgba` directive so you are supposed to pass 4 values (r,g,b,a)

```
var $nDiv = $('<div></div>')
$nDiv.draggable(); 
var color = "rgba(120,120,120,1)";
canvas.append($nDiv);
$nDiv.css('backgroundColor',color);
```

If you just want to set the color and not the alpha make sure you use `rgb()`

```
var color = "rgb(120,120,120)";
```

**Extra:**

> jQuery support both [these notations](http://api.jquery.com/css/): "backgroundColor" , "background-color"

Answer (score 1):

1. `rgba()` accept 4 arguments
2. It should be `background-color` rather than `backgroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.  Remove the a from rgba, so that it's just "rgb(120,120,120)".

Secondly, the css style for background color is "background-color".